# How to count the number of characters at the start of a string?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, count

How can I count the number of characters at the start/end of a string in Python?

For example, if the string is

```
'ffffhuffh'
```

How would I count the number of `f`s at the **start** of the string? The above string with a `f` should output 4.

[`str.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) is not useful to me as a character could be in the middle of the string.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

A short and simple way will be to use the `str.lstrip` method, and count the difference of length.

```
s = 'ffffhuffh'
print(len(s)-len(s.lstrip('f')))
# output: 4
```

[`str.lstrip([chars])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip):

> Return a copy of the string with leading characters removed. The chars
>   argument is a string specifying the set of characters to be removed.

Answer (score 9):

Try this, using [itertools.takewhile()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile):

```
import itertools as it

s = 'ffffhuffh'
sum(1 for _ in it.takewhile(lambda c: c == 'f', s))
=> 4
```

Similarly, for counting the characters at the end:

```
s = 'huffhffff'
sum(1 for _ in it.takewhile(lambda c: c == 'f', reversed(s)))
=> 4
```

Comment: `sum(1 for _ in takewhile(lambda c: c == 'f', 'ffffhuffh'))` avoids building a list.

Comment: @timgeb nice! I updated my answer with your suggestion, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may use *regular expression* with [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) to find the occurrence of any character at the start of the string as:

```
>>> import re
>>> my_str = 'ffffhuffh'
>>> my_char = 'f'

>>> len(re.match('{}*'.format(my_char), my_str).group())
4
```

Comment: I suggest `re.match(...).group()` instead of `re.findall(...)[0]` to avoid searching the entire string.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function and iterate through your string and return the count of the desired char in the input string's beginning or end like this example:

```
# start = True: Count the chars at the beginning of the string
# start = False: Count the chars at the end of the string
def count_char(string= '', char='', start=True):
    count = 0
    if not start:
        string = string[::-1]

    for k in string:
        if k is char:
            count += 1
        else:
            break
    return count

a = 'ffffhuffh'
print(count_char(a, 'f'))
b = a[::-1]
print(count_char(b, 'f', start=False))
```

Output:

```
4
4
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on Oscar Lopez's answer, I want to handle the case you mention of the end of the string: use `reversed()`

```
import itertools as it

my_string = 'ffffhuffh'

len(list(it.takewhile(lambda c: c == my_string[-1], reversed(my_string))))
=> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to find the count of the occurrence of the first element at the start of the string as:

```
from itertools import groupby

def get_first_char_count(my_str):
    return len([list(j) for _, j in groupby(my_str)][0])
```

Sample run:

```
>>> get_first_char_count('ffffhuffh')
4
>>> get_first_char_count('aywsnsb')
1
```

Answer (score 0):

re.sub select first letter with repeat( (^(\w)\2*) ), len count frequency.

```
len(re.sub(r'((^\w)\2*).*',r'\1',my_string))
```